# Processbuider do not execute application only in windows 7 32bit

Tags: java, windows, applet, processbuilder

I have faced interesting issue where my signed Java applet is unable to run process via ProcessBuilder only under Windows 7 32bit. I've tested applet on Windows 7 64 bit, Windows Vista 32bit and Windows 8 32/64 bits with Java 7 and Java 8 and it was working flawlessly. Problem seems to be that the application which I'm trying to run from my applet needs higher permissions which Java cannot provide. So what I'm looking to hear is there any workaround (registry patch or something) in order to provide needed security rights for Java?

Tested solutions:

1. Applet manifest modified with added line: **Permissions: all-permissions**;
2. Run as Administrator IE, Mozilla browsers;
3. Modified c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\java.policy with line: **permission java.security.AllPermission**;

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution! If you trying to lounch any executable application from Java applet which requires Administrator rights, you must put your executable to System32 directory.